# Generate multiple PDF at once in EZPDF

Tags: php, pdf, ezpdf

I don't know why its not working. I've used while loop to generate multiple pdfs with ezpdf class, and only 1 pdf is creating. I also tried 'for loop' but is still the same . What should i do to achieve more than one pdf?

```
include ('class.ezpdf.php');
$limit = 1;
while($limit < 5){
  $colw = array(      80 ,    40,   220,    80,     40  );//column widths
 $rows = array(
     array('company','size','desc','cost','instock'),
     array("WD", "80GB","WD800AAJS SATA2 7200rpm 8mb"        ,"$36.90","Y"),

 );

 //x is 0-600, y is 0-780 (origin is at bottom left corner)
 $pdf =& new Cezpdf('LETTER');

 $total=0;
 $curr_x=80;
 $curr_y=600;
 foreach($rows as $r)
 {
     $xoffset = $curr_x;
     foreach($r as $i=>$data)
     {
         $pdf->setColor(0/255,0/255,0/255);
         $pdf->addText( $xoffset, $curr_y , 10, $data );
         $xoffset+=$colw[$i];
     }
     $curr_y-=20;
 }
define('MY_FILENAME', 'testDoc'.$limit.'.pdf');
$pdfcode = $pdf->ezOutput();
$fp = fopen(MY_FILENAME, 'wb');
fwrite($fp, $pdfcode);
fclose($fp); 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I think your problem occurs because you try to set a constant value with **define()** in a loop.
I tested it and the define-variable (MY_FILENAME) had always the same value inside a loop. It seems that PHP doesn't set defined variables again.

Your solution woul'd be to replace your define variable (MY_FILENAME) with a regular variable like this...

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    $myPDFFile = "PDF" . $i . ".pdf";

    $pdf = new Cezpdf('A4');    // create CezPDF-object

    // write content to PDF-file

    $pdfCode = $pdf->output();  // content of PDF to variable

    $file = fopen($myPDFFile, "wb");
    fwrite($file, $pdfCode);
    fclose($file);
}
```

instead of

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    define(MY_FILENAME, "testDoc" . $i . ".pdf");
    ...
}
```

I hope this woul'd work for you.